# ERROR: FirebasePerformancePlugin must only be used with Android application projects. can't in Library?

Tags: android, firebase, android-sdk-2.3, firebase-performance

I have built a project with all Firebase features including Firebase Performance Plugin. Now we are trying to make it as Library, While trying to convert from Application to Library we are facing an issue from Firebase as

ERROR: FirebasePerformancePlugin must only be used with Android application projects. Need to apply the 'com.android.application' plugin with this plugin.

May I know the reason why I am facing this issue. I am excepting a quick reply from the Team.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory: you can only apply the Firebase Performance Plugin to an application. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, Firebase Performance Monitoring is not supported for libraries, only apps.  You currently can't use the product to collect performance information for you library if it gets integrated into other apps.  You can only use it for monitor the behavior of a specific app that's added to your Firebase project.

If this is not what you want, you can [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  Though, for this request, I suspect nothing will happen in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Doug Stevenson.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Doug Stevenson. Can't I use only Firebase performance SDK as library or all the Firebase SDK's can't be converted?
The reason is I have removed all the Firebae performance plugins (App Level and Project Level Gradle Files) Then I am getting a new issue like 

"ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension."

I tried with adding Application variants and Library Variants it didn't work. Any Suggestions please